# Interpreting poincare and Euclidean group modules as manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, modules, manifolds

If I have a module of the Poincare/Euclidean group can I interpret this as a manifold with a Poincare/Euclidean symmetry?

It seems like the translations subgroups acting on the module could be interpreted as picking a point on the manifold and translating it around. However there is also the rotations/boosts of the remaining Poincare/Euclidean group that appears to be irrelevant in this interpretation, and thus makes me think of the corresponding tangent bundles.

My question is if there is a rigourous way to state that these modules may be interpreted as a manifold or as a tangent bundle? Or if not in general are there additional requirements that the module can satisfy for this to be the case?

Comment: This can be done for a transitive group action by a Lie group $G$ on a set $M$, but modules are never transitive. It's perhaps illustrative that the additive identity $0\in M$ is not "translated" by $G$ at all.

Comment: Good point, so does that mean we could split up a module M, so that it is a direct sum of manifolds in some respect, i.e. if we consider Lie group $G = GL(n)$ and our module as vector space $M = \mathbb{R}^{n}$ then we could think of $M$ as a sum of a manifold $\mathbb{R}^{n}/\{0\}$ (over which $GL(n)$ acts transitively) and a left-over component (possibly a seperate trivial manifold) $\{0\}$?

Comment: You could look at $G$-orbits individually like that, but even when the $G$-orbits are well behaved, there isn't an obvious way to equip left-over part $M/G$ with a topology or smooth structure that makes $M$ into (some generalization of) a manifold.

Comment: Considering the example above I could imagine you have the set $\mathbb{R}^{n}/\{0\}$ would be a manifold, and then separately you have the manifold $\{0\}$ which is a trivial manifold with a topology given by open sets $\{\{0\}, \{\}\}$. I can't see this as obviously being a manifold with any extra structure (e.g. smooth/differentiable ect). But I guess its a manifold. In which case you could take disjoint sets of $M$ which are connected by $G$ within each set and obtain a disjoint union of manifolds (though it may have to be an uncountably infinite disjoint union).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is what you are after, but a module by definition is a finite dimensional vector space and thus a manifold in an obvious way.

Comment: That isn't true in general, a module has an action on it from a ring rather than from a field. Every finite dimensional vector space is a module, but not every module is a finite dimensional vector space. If the ring in question contains a field then I could see a forgetful functor mapping from modules to vector spaces, but if you contain the entire underlying set of the module as the underlying set of the vector space this could lead to a ring modulo field graded vector space (which I see not reason must be finite).

Comment: However restricting the modules to only finite dimensional vector spaces might be an interesting idea

Comment: Since you are working in the setting of Lie groups, I would view "module" as synonymous with "representation" which means that this is a vector space. Otherwise, you should specify what you mean by a module.

Comment: I was specifically considering the module of an associative algebra $A$ where the associative algebra's automorphism group $\mathrm{Aut}(A)$ contained the Lie group $G$ in question. Since we have the Lie group action on the algebra then we can also induce a Lie group action on the A-module. At this point you have an abelian group with a group action on it. While it seems to me that this would give a free $G$-module it isn't clear to me that I can reduce this down to a vector space (and thus a manifold).

Comment: Though it seems like the lie group may also inherent some additive operator from the algebra to make it a ring.

Comment: I don't think that an action of a Lie group on an algebra automatically gives rise to an action on each module over the algebra. In any case, these are not standard notions, so I believe you'll have to clarify the concepts you are using before you can hope to get good answers to your question.